# difference between raise Exception("Something is wrong") and sys.exit("Something is wrong")

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading codes from senior colleagues and he use `sys.exit("something is wrong")` a lot instead of `raise Exception("something is wrong")`. I did a quick test:

```
sys.exit("something is wrong")
```

output:

```
something is wrong

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
raise Exception("something is wrong")
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/gitlab/developer/my_developer/api.py", line 977, in <module>
    raise Exception("something is wrong")
Exception: something is wrong

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It appears to me that the `raise Exception("something is wrong")` provide `traceback` information which shows in which line this error occurs, which can help a lot for narrowing down the lines causing the error. and in `sys.exit("something is wrong")` it just printed a error message without any more info. to me `raise Exception` appears more helpful but I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Thanks

Comment: I think this will be a very situational question. If i am asking a user for an input between 1 and 10 its cleaner to just call sys.exit with message that the number was not valid rather than dumping a stack trace on the user. However if i am writting code to be called by some other code then raising exceptions at least allows that other code to handle the problem. similarly like you say sometimes the traceback will be useful to the developer to debug the error. But really it will come down to situation and preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends what you are looking for. The two have very different meanings.
sys.exit('something is wrong') will always exit the program with that message. It is cleaner for the end user to not have to worry about the technical stacktrace.
raise Exception('Something is wrong') will raison an exception with that message. If it is uncaught it will exit the program and print a stacktrace allowing the programmer to see why the exception happened and if it is caught in the code it allows the programmer to code what should happen next if the exception is raised and the program continues.
It all depends on what the programmer wants to do!